# How to add index post writing

Tags: indexing

so I have written a significant part of my thesis. Unfortunately, I did not think of the possibility of adding index till now. Fortunately, however, I did have the sense to define a new command, which I called \define to define new terms.

I would like all these definitions to appear in the index. What would be the best way to achieve that? I was thinking to replace anything like

```
\define{something to be defined}
```

by something like

```
\index{\define{something to be defined}}
```

but that has a problem because of the last curly brace } because every time a new term is defined.

Another idea is to change the definition of define to include the index command. Currently, my \define looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\define}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}
```

Is it good form to change this definition to

```
\newcommand{\define}[1]{\textbf{\emph{\index{#1}}}}
```

or some variant of it? Or do I have to change everything manually as a last resort?

Comment: `\newcommand{\define}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}\index{#1}}`

Comment: @egreg That worked like a charm! Why not convert it into an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Bobyandbob you are right, but I feel that it could be of use to future visitors. Ideally, egreg would convert his comment to answer but if not, go ahead and please close.

Comment: With `@` you could ping involved people. @egreg would you like to write an answer to help future visitors?